# hbase error: "10/12/26 06:48:07 INFO ipc.HbaseRPC: Server at /127.0.0.1:58920 could not be reached after 1 tries, giving up."

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Dose anyone know what's wrong with hbase? I am using vm image of cloudera distribution for hadoop, previously it was working fine but now giving me this error after every second when i try to list all the tables:

**10/12/26 06:48:07 INFO ipc.HbaseRPC: Server at /127.0.0.1:58920 could not be reached after 1 tries, giving up.**

Comment: In my case for the same issue, below link helped me out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205057/how-to-fix-corrupt-hadoop-hdfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 11.10. Default installation added a line in /etc/hosts which linked my machine hostname with the IP 127.0.1.1.
I changed this link to point to 127.0.0.1 and Hbase started working.

Also,solutions of similar problem on other computers ware either to disable IP tables or to comment out IPv6 addresses in /etc/hosts.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the configuration.  For some reason it can't see either where the zookeeper quorum is or where the hbase master is.  You should never see 127.0.0.1 in your logs.  Probably the configuration file is missing or incorrect.  I believe that there is an hbase FAQ on this:
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Troubleshooting