# hdfs data got corrupted. the corrupted folder cannot be deleted as it shows no such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My hdfs data got corrupted.

on doing fsck, i got the following result 
.
/siva: CORRUPT block blk_-1910702044505537827

/siva: CORRUPT block blk_6483992593913191763

/siva: MISSING 2 blocks of total size 82009995 B.Status: CORRUPT
 Total size:    82009995 B
 Total dirs:    8
 Total files:   1
 Total blocks (validated):      2 (avg. block size 41004997 B)

---

CORRUPT FILES:        1
  MISSING BLOCKS:       2
  MISSING SIZE:         82009995 B
  CORRUPT BLOCKS:       2

---

Minimally replicated blocks:   0 (0.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    2
 Average block replication:     0.0
 Corrupt blocks:                2
 Missing replicas:              0
 Number of data-nodes:          1
 Number of racks:               1
FSCK ended at Tue Feb 23 12:21:03 IST 2016 in 2 milliseconds

The filesystem under path '/' is CORRUPT

Then i tried to remove the /siva folder but i got the following output
rmr: cannot remove /siva: No such file or directory.

please support

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205057/how-to-fix-corrupt-hadoop-hdfs

Answer (score 0):

Use `hdfs fsck / -delete` to remove corrupted files.

Comment: hadoop fsck /siva -delete
FSCK started by hadoop from /xxx.xxx.xxx.xx for path /siva at Tue Feb 23 18:03:01 IST 2016


Path '/siva' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

1. Please run the below command on any headnode[ HN0 or HN1].
   hdfs fsck -D "fs.default.name=hdfs://mycluster/" /
2. In the report, we can see a filesystem as corrupt since blocks are got corrupted.
   The filesystem under path '/' is CORRUPT
3. Run the below command to fix this issue.
4. hdfs fsck -D "fs.default.name=hdfs://mycluster/" / -delete
5. after, run the below command again to see a filesystem status.
6. hdfs fsck -D "fs.default.name=hdfs://mycluster/" /
7. this time we should see the filesytem status as Healthy like below.
   The filesystem under path '/' is HEALTHY