# Corrupted block in hdfs cluster

Tags: hadoop, corrupt-data

The screenshot added below shows the output of `hdfs fsck /`. It shows that the "/" directory is corrupted. This is the masternode of my Hadoop cluster. What to do?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205057/how-to-fix-corrupt-hdfs-files

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hadoop 2, you can run a Standby namenode to achieve High Availability. Without that, your cluster's master will be a Single Point of Failure.

You can not retrieve the data of Namenode from anywhere else since it is different from the usual data you store. If your namenode goes down, your blocks and files will still be there, but you won't be able to access them since there would be no related metadata in the namenode.