# how to manage corrupted files/blocks in hadoop clusters

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We have Hadoop cluster version HDP – 26 , on redhat machines version 7.x

We run the following command to capture the files that have corrupted blocks

Example 1

```
[root@master_3 ~]# su hdfs
[hdfs@master_3 root]$ hdfs fsck -list-corruptfileblocks 

blk_1097240344/localhdp/Rtrone/intercept_by_type/2018/4/10/16/2018_4_03_11_45.parquet/part-00002-be0f80a9-2c7c-4c50-b18d-db0f94a98cff.snly.parquet
blk_1097240348/localhdp/Rtrone/intkjd_country/2018/4/10/16/2018_4_03_11_45.parquet/part-00003-8600d0e2-c6b6-49b7-89cd-ef243cda4c5e.snly.parquet
The filesystem under path '/' has 2 CORRUPT files
```

so seems the files are:

```
/localhdp/Rtrone/intercept_by_type/2018/4/10/16/2018_4_03_11_45.parquet/part-00002-be0f80a9-2c7c-4c50-b18d-db0f94a98cff.snly.parquet
/localhdp/Rtrone/intkjd_country/2018/4/10/16/2018_4_03_11_45.parquet/part-00003-8600d0e2-c6b6-49b7-89cd-ef243cda4c5e.snly.parquet
```

searching on google , I understand that the procedure to handle the corrupted block in files should be as the following:

1. This will delete the corrupted HDFS blocks:

   hdfs fsck / -delete
2. run again the hdfs fsck -list-corruptfileblocks to find out if corrupted block deleted successfully

   hdfs fsck -list-corruptfileblocks
3. if corrupted blocks still exists  ( as example 1 ) then we need to delete the files as the following

   hdfs fs -rm /localhdp/Rtrone/intercept_by_type/2018/4/10/16/2018_4_03_11_45.parquet/part-00002-be0f80a9-2c7c-4c50-b18d-db0f94a98cff.snly.parquet

   hdfs fs -rm /localhdp/Rtrone/intkjd_country/2018/4/10/16/2018_4_03_11_45.parquet/part-00003-8600d0e2-c6b6-49b7-89cd-ef243cda4c5e.snly.parquet

*am I right or I miss something?*

Please let me know what need to add or update regarding my procedure

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I see in stack overflow many similar questions with the same subject as my question as - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205057/how-to-fix-corrupt-hdfs-files so what is the diff here why my question isn't fit for stackoverflow?

Comment: The rules of the sites can change over the years. But given the question is server administration, not programming, it makes sense to be asked elsewhere. (even though Stackoverflow will almost always be top Google hit)

Comment: @cricket_007 since I not get answer until now , can you please help me to understand if my solution is the right approach?

Comment: You need to delete the corrupted blocks, yes. If you list them, then you find them and delete. What's the issue?

Comment: @cricket_007 dose my steps 1-3 are ok?

Comment: You're misusing the word "Does". And the correct way to say that is "Are my steps ok". But, as posted in the answer, and the link you have, yes... Delete the listed files

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is very simple.Follow

1. Find out the corrupted blocks

   ```
     hdfs fsck / | egrep -v '^\.+$' | grep -v eplica
   ```
2. Find out files related to corrupted blocks

   ```
    hdfs fsck /path/to/corrupt/file -locations -blocks -files
   ```
3. Remove the corrupted File

   ```
    hdfs fs -rm /Corrupted_File_Path
   ```

After these steps rerun "hdfs fsck /" to see that missing blocks are gone.